# How to use spring security in integration tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test-mvc

I have a following `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` implementation:

```
@Configuration
@Order(0)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final List<String> permittedPaths = asList();
    private static final String protectedPath = "";

    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private final JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public SecurityConfiguration(
        UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService,
        JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider,
        DataSource dataSource
    ) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.jwtAuthenticationProvider = jwtAuthenticationProvider;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {}

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider);
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("")
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

This security works fine for normal running application. But in tests - fails.
I have an integration test like:

```
@WebMvcTest(SomeController.class)
@Import({ErrorHandlerConfiguration.class})
class SomeControllerItTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private RegistrationService registrationService;

    @Test
    void shouldConfirmRegistration() {}
}
```

and after run, I get following error:

> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration' defined in file
> [SecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed
> through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'UserDetailsServiceImpl' available: expected
> at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
> annotations: {}

When I add to this test `SecurityConfiguration` class beans:

```
@MockBean
private JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;
@MockBean
private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
@MockBean
private DataSource dataSource;
```

tests runs normally, without any `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` exceptions.

This solution isn't enough for me. Is there any other way to avoid putting security beans to each integrtation tests?

I tried to use:

- `@Import({ErrorHandlerConfiguration.class, SecurityConfiguration.class})`
- `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SecurityConfiguration.class})`

without any results.

(removed methods body and some strings for brevity)

// EDIT
Attached missing classes, which are injected into `SecurityConfiguration`:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
//method implementation
}

@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
//method implementation
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will be to any help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63508842/14072498

Comment: Thanks for the link. But main difference is that `@SpringBootTest` runs whole ApplicationContext (i.e. with persistence layer) which is not needed for me to integration test which testing a controller responses. Maybe there isn't any other option and I must run whole context. Anyway thans for tip.

Comment: why is your constructor in `SecurityConfiguration` empty?

Comment: @Toerktumlare constructor is empty for brevity. Parameters are assigned to class fields. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@WebMvcTest(
    value = SomeController.class,
    excludeAutoConfiguration = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
            type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
            classes = WebSecurityConfigurer.class))
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
public class SomeControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your first example with `excludeFilters` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)` works! Thanks for tip.

Answer (score 0):

this is a qualified guess, but for some reason you  have not posted the class that is missing `UserDetailsServiceImpl`.

If you read the documentation about `WebMvcTest` it states:

> `@WebMvcTest` auto-configures the Spring MVC infrastructure and limits scanned beans to `@Controller`, `@ControllerAdvice`, `@JsonComponent`, `Converter`, `GenericConverter`, `Filter`, `HandlerInterceptor`, `WebMvcConfigurer`, and `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.

> Regular `@Component` and `@ConfigurationProperties` beans are not scanned when the `@WebMvcTest` annotation is used. `@EnableConfigurationProperties` can be used to include `@ConfigurationProperties` beans.

So im guessing your bean isn't picked up for this reason, its all stated in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests).

But as said, this is a guess because for some reason you have not posted the code that is missing for us to take a look at, and there are several unknows, as to the empty constructor, and other empty functions.

Comment: I added classes which are injected into `SecurityConfiguration`.